# Problems in displaying multi-line chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i'm trying to create a multi-line chart,with two lines and two different colors,I've followed the guide on http://www.delimited.io/blog/2014/3/3/creating-multi-series-charts-in-d3-lines-bars-area-and-streamgraphs but in my case,it does not work,and I'm wondering why.
My tsv file is this http://wikisend.com/download/732088/difference.tsv]difference.tsv

The code

```
<html style="height: 100%">
<head>
    <title>Information Visualization</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.js"> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3.tip.js"> </script>
    <style type="text/css">
    .axis {
                    font: 9px sans-serif;

            }
            .axis path,
            .axis line {
                    fill: none;
                    stroke: #000;
                    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
            }

           /* .x.axis path {
                    display: none;
            }*/

            #MainVisualization{
                    float:left;
                    /*min-width:1024px;*/
                    width:50%;
                    margin-left:0.5%;
                    margin-right:0.5%;
                    margin-top:0.5%;
                    min-height:300px;
                    height:40%;
                    background-color: white;
            }
            #LineChart{
                    float:left;
                    /*min-width:1024px;*/
                    /*width:100%;*/
                    margin-left:0.5%;
                    margin-right:0.5%;
                    margin-top:0.5%;
                    /*min-height:768px;*/
                    height:48%;
                    background-color: yellow;
            }

            #Command-Area{
                    width:100%;
                    height:2%;
                    background-color: green;
                    opacity:0.7;
            }
            #Title{
                    margin: 0;
                    margin-bottom: 0.5%;
                    text-align: center;
                    font-family: sans-serif;
                    font-size: 250%;
                    color: goldenrod;
            }
            .line{
                fill:none;
                stroke: steelblue;
                stroke-width:1.5px;
            }
            #tooltip {
                position: fixed;
                width: 100px;
                height: auto;
                padding: 10px;
                background-color: orange;
                -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
                -moz-border-radius: 10px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            #tooltip.hidden {
                 display: none;
            }

            #tooltip p {
                margin: 0;
                font-family: sans-serif;
                font-size: 16px;
                line-height: 20px;
            }
            .d3-tip {
                line-height: 1;
                font-weight: bold;
                padding: 12px;
                background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
                color: #fff;
                border-radius: 2px;
            }

            .d3-tip:after {
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: inline;
                font-size: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                line-height: 1;
                color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
                content: "\25BC";
                position: absolute;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .d3-tip.n:after {
                margin: -1px 0 0 0;
                top: 100%;
                left: 0;
            }

</style>
</head>
<body style="height:100%"> 
    <h1 id="Title" >Difference between  2003 to 2010</h1>
    <div id="Command-Area"></div>
    <div id="tooltip" class="hidden">    
    <div id="MainVisualization">

    </div>
    <div id="LineChart">

    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        var containerWidth,containerHeight;

        containerWidth=document.getElementById("MainVisualization").offsetWidth;
        containerHeight=document.getElementById("MainVisualization").offsetHeight;

        console.log("------ "+containerWidth+ " "+containerHeight);

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
        width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        var padding = 20;
        var dataset;


        var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
        var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]);
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height,0]);
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                      .scale(xScale)
                      .orient("bottom");
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");


        var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
                     .x(function(d){
                            return xScale(d.anno);
                    })
                     .y(function(d){
                         return yScale(+d.value);
                    })


        var tip2 = d3.tip()
                    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
                    .offset([ -10, 0 ]).html(
                        function(d) {
                            return "<strong>% People:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.Totale + "</span>";
                    })   

        /******* multi line chart ********/    
        containerWidth=document.getElementById("MainVisualization").offsetWidth;
        containerHeight=document.getElementById("MainVisualization").offsetHeight;



        var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                      .range(["#9c8305","#d3c47c"]);

        d3.tsv("resources/difference.tsv",function(data){

            var labelVar = 'anno';
            var varNames = d3.keys(data[0])
                             .filter(function(key){ return key !== labelVar;});
            color.domain(varNames);

            var seriesData = varNames.map(function(name){
                return{
                    name: name,
                    values: data.map(function(d){
                        return {name: name, anno: d[labelVar], value: +d[name]};
                    })
                };
            });
            console.log("serieData",seriesData);


            var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40};
            width = containerWidth - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = containerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y").parse;
            var xScale = d3.time.scale().range([0,width]);
            var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height,0]);
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                          .scale(xScale)
                          .orient("bottom");
            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left");


            var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("linear")
                         .x(function(d){
                            return xScale(d.anno);
                        })
                         .y(function(d){
                             return yScale(d.value);
                        })

            var svg = d3.select("#LineChart")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          //  svg.call(tip2);

            svg.append("svg:text")
               .text("Men's internet usage from 2003 to 2013")
               .attr("x","40%")
               .attr("y","6%")
               .attr("font-size","100%")
               .attr("dx","-25%")
               .attr("fill","red");

            data.forEach(function(d) {
                d.anno = parseDate(d.anno.toString());     
            });

           yAxis.tickFormat(function(d){return d + "%"});


            yScale.domain([
                    d3.min(seriesData, function(c) {
                        return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.value; });
                    }),
                    d3.max(seriesData, function(c) {
                        return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.value; });
                    })
            ]);


            xScale.domain(d3.extent(data,function(d){
                return +d.anno;
            }));



           svg.append("g")
               .attr("class","x axis")
               .attr("transform","translate(0," + height +")")
               .call(xAxis);

            svg.append("g")
               .attr("class","y axis")
               .call(yAxis)
               .append("text")
               .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
               .attr("y", 6)
               .attr("dy", ".71em")
               .style("text-anchor", "end")
               .text("Frequency");

    var series = svg.selectAll(".series").data(seriesData)
                    .enter().append("g").attr("class","series");

            series.append("path")
               .attr("class","line")
               .attr("d",function(d){ return line(d.values); })
               .style("stroke","black")
               .style("stroke-width", "4px")
               .style("fill", "none");
             //  .transition().duration(2500).attrTween("d",pathTween);

         /*function pathTween() {
                var interpolate = d3.scale.quantile()
                                    .domain([0,1])
                                    .range(d3.range(1, data.length + 1));
                return function(t) {
                    return line(data.slice(0, interpolate(t)));
                };
            }*/

     /*       svg.selectAll("circle")
               .data(datiInternet)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr("cx",function(d){
                   return xScale(d.anno);
                })
               .attr("cy",function(d){
                   return yScale(d.value);
                })
               .attr("r",5)
               .on('mouseover', tip2.show).on('mouseout', tip2.hide);           
   */

        });


    </script>


</body>
```

What I see are only the two axes,I can't figure out what is wrong.
Maybe the error is in retrieving line(d.values),with the console d.values gives me an array and for each element of the array I need the "value" element.
Please help me I'm blocked here,thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There seemed to be a lot wrong with your code. (if you look at the DOM all of the line chart was getting put under the tooltip div.) Here is a working barebones version of what I think you were looking for.

http://bl.ocks.org/JoshFerge/5e7622d010271fb4082f